# GASで色のついたセルにだけ番号を振るには？

Tags: google-apps-script

今までExcelのVBAで行っていた動作があるのですが、スプレッドシートに変更になり動かなくなってしまいました。
GASを使用したことがなく、どのようにしたら今までの動作が再現できるか分かりません…。

A列の決まった背景色のついたセル(今回の場合「黄色」)にだけ番号を振る、というものです。
VBAでは、

```vba
Dim c As Range, i As Long
For Each c In Selection
    If c.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
        c = c + i + 1
        i = i + 1
    End if
Next c
```

と記載し、検索したいセル範囲を手動で選んでマクロを起動していました。

GASでどのようにすればこの挙動が再現できるのか分かるかたがいましたらご教示ください。

Answer (score 1):

以下のようなので挙動を再現できます。

```
function myFunction() {
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = activeSheet.getSelection().getActiveRange();
  var bgColors = range.getBackgrounds();
  var values = range.getValues();
  var num = 1;
  for (var i in bgColors) {
    for (var j in bgColors[i]) {
      if(bgColors[i][j] === "#ffff00")
        values[i][j] = num++;
    }
  }
  range.setValues(values);
}
```